# How to start a job 1 hour after I click Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, I want to be able to delay the execution of a job, i.e. for 1 hour, after I click Build.

I want to set up the parameters, click Build and the job to stay in the Queue for 1 hour, without using an executor, and then start. I do not want to schedule a job periodically or sth like that. Just to force it to stay in the queue for a certain (maybe configurable) period of time.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about using `sleep`?

Comment: Sleep is an option yes but I think it it will consume an entire node that will be just idling. Thanks, I may have to resort to that if no other options appear.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sleep` here is exactly the right thing to do. To workaround the fact that no new nodes are consumed and idle, just execute the sleep command on a special sleepnode. So every Job will use this sleepnode for sleeping, which means no additional nodes would get consumed.

```
node('sleeper') {
  stage('Countdown 1hr') {
    sleep 3600
  }
}
node('buildnode1') {
  stage('build') {
    echo "What ever should be done here"
  }
}
```